All transaction return "Signature XXXXXX has expired: block height exceeded."
I try to swap USDT to other token through SWAP API but it got the same error.block height exceeded.
this is my swap function
async function handleSwap(wallet: any, coinName: string, amount: number) {
  if (!wallet.connected || !wallet.signTransaction) {
    toast.error("Please connect your wallet first", {
      position: "bottom-center"
    });
    return;
  }

  const fromToken = "USDT";
  const fromMint = TOKEN_MINTS[fromToken];
  const toMint = TOKEN_MINTS[coinName];

  if (!fromMint || !toMint) {
    toast.error(`Unsupported token pair: ${fromToken} to ${coinName}`, {
      position: "bottom-center"
    });
    return;
  }

  try {
    const amountInDecimals = amount;
    const quoteUrl = `https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/quote?inputMint=${fromMint}&outputMint=${toMint}&amount=${amountInDecimals}&slippageBps=50`;
    const quoteResponse = await fetch(quoteUrl).then((res) => res.json());

    if (!quoteResponse || quoteResponse.error) {
      throw new Error(quoteResponse.error || "Failed to get quote");
    }

    const swapRequestBody = {
      quoteResponse,
      userPublicKey: wallet.publicKey.toString(),
      wrapAndUnwrapSol: true,
      computeUnitPriceMicroLamports: 50000,
      priorityLevelWithMaxLamports: {
        priorityLevel: "high",
        maxLamports: 100000
      },

    };

    const { swapTransaction } = await fetch(
      "https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/swap",
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(swapRequestBody)
      }
    ).then((res) => res.json());

    const swapTransactionBuf = Buffer.from(swapTransaction, "base64");
    const transaction = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(swapTransactionBuf);

    // Get latest blockhash before signing
    const latestBlockhash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash("confirmed");
    transaction.message.recentBlockhash = latestBlockhash.blockhash;

    const signedTransaction = await wallet.signTransaction(transaction);
    const rawTransaction = signedTransaction.serialize();

    // Function to send transaction with retries
    const sendTransactionWithRetry = async (
      rawTx: Buffer,
      maxRetries = 3,
      retryDelay = 1000
    ): Promise<string> => {
      let lastError;

      for (let i = 0; i < maxRetries; i++) {
        try {
          const txid = await connection.sendRawTransaction(rawTx, {
            skipPreflight: true,
            maxRetries: 2,
            preflightCommitment: "confirmed"
          });

          // Wait for confirmation with a timeout
          const status = await Promise.race([
            connection.confirmTransaction({
              signature: txid,
              blockhash: latestBlockhash.blockhash,
              lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockhash.lastValidBlockHeight
            }),
            new Promise((_, reject) =>
              setTimeout(() => reject(new Error("Confirmation timeout")), 30000)
            )
          ]);

          if ((status as any).value.err) {
            throw new Error("Transaction failed");
          }

          return txid;
        } catch (error) {
          lastError = error;
          if (i < maxRetries - 1) {
            await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, retryDelay));
            // Get fresh blockhash for retry
            const newBlockhash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash(
              "confirmed"
            );
            transaction.message.recentBlockhash = newBlockhash.blockhash;
            const newSignedTx = await wallet.signTransaction(transaction);
            rawTx = newSignedTx.serialize();
          }
        }
      }
      throw lastError;
    };

    const txid = await sendTransactionWithRetry(rawTransaction);
    console.log(`https://solscan.io/tx/${txid}`);

    toast.success("Transaction confirmed!", {
      position: "bottom-center"
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error signing or sending the transaction:", error);
    toast.error(
      `Transaction failed: ${
        error instanceof Error ? error.message : "Unknown error"
      }`,
      {
        position: "bottom-center"
      }
    );
  }
}```


This question is similar to: How can I analyze the reason for frequent BlockHeightExceeded errors?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It's not due to the program itself.
You should use better rpc.
If you use paid plan for rpc or staked url, then you can effectively fix that error.
